# How can I use Varnish cache on a different location and provider than my web servers?

Tags: cache, varnish, linode

I'm trying to put Varnish in front of my Linode servers located in Tokyo. My user base is in India, so serving cached content directly from India would be speeding up my web application with lower latency due to less geographical distance.

I have a Digital Ocean droplet (since Linode doesn't have Indian servers) in India which I want to use as the HTTP Acclerator standing in front of the Linode servers in Tokyo.

I've read the docs where it says that l will need to use the private IP of my instance, but that's not possible because of the geographial isolation and different providers.

How do I go on achieving that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to use private IP of your instances. You can use your Linode servers public IP addresses in Varnish backend definition. It will work fine.

Comment: Will the speed be hampered while exchanging information between varnish and the web servers?

Comment: Of course the performance will vary based on the type of link between your Varnish and backend servers. In this case they will be linked via global network. Private network link would be ideal but not possible between two providers. Considering that most of your content will be cached by Varnish - speed will be ok for end users.